# Providing a Blazor GUI from a .NET Core Console App

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, .net-core

I am developing a computation and resource heavy back-end .NET Core **console** application that runs continuously in the background. In Windows, this console application will run as a Windows Service using something like NSSM. In Linux, it will run as a daemon.

In order to configure this background application, I would like to provide a Razor-based HTML5 GUI.  In principle, this is similar to how a house-hold router works -- runs in the background and provides an HTML admin GUI.

**QUESTION 1:** Is it possible to achieve this?

**QUESTION 2:** Can you provide general outline of the startup/config code to make this work?